# Friction is also a conservative force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, friction, conservative-field

I have asked a [recent question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/652804/) about how spring force is conservative and in that I learnt that for a force to be conservative ***the work done by the force should be path independent given the initial and final states of the system is the same***. The condition on states is most important part of the definition which is going to be used below.

---

Now I think with this definition I can prove that *friction force is also conservative* but I am not sure if I am correct or not. Here's my intuition :-

Suppose we have *a rough horizontal table* and a block is kept on it at some point A. We can call this as our initial state of the system.

## Case 1:-

Suppose that **we displace the block slowly on that rough table on a straight path to some point B**.

[image]

Now because of friction opposing the motion of the block, the molecules in the table and that of the block will start vibrating and so we can define the final state at point B in which molecules of both the table and the block are vibrating at some frequency (no matter how small they are). *I think we can also use the temperature of  the system after (being displaced to point B) to define our final state*.

## Case 2:-

Now if the same block is displaced slowly from the **same initial state** to the **same final position** but on a different path (let's say on two diagonal lines **meeting at point C in that same horizontal plane**), the friction will act for a longer distance and for a longer time and thus will do more work.

[image]

But the main thing to notice here is that ***the state of the body in this case at final position is not the same*** ("since the molecules of both the block and the table will now be vibrating at a faster rate since friction acted over a longer distance (as well as longer time) or to say that the temperature of the system would be higher than that in the first case") which means that **we cannot compare the work done by friction in these two cases to define whether it is conservative or not**.

***Remember the fact tha we must compare work done between same initial and final state to define conservativeness***.

So this means that **we should first make the final state of the system same as that it is in the first case in which the block was displaced directly from A to B** and also follow a different path than the one taken in that case to define conservativeness.

## Case 3:-

So suppose the block is displaced for the **same distance** it travelled in the first case but in a different direction to a point C and then raised up vertically and is then brought to a point which is vertically above point B and then **slowly brought down at the point B**.

[image]

This time the friction acted for the same time and the same distance and thus the vibration or **the temperature of the system will be the same** and **so we can now compare the work done by friction in this case and in case 1** and by coincidence we get the fact that the work done by friction is same in both these paths which means that friction is also a conservative force.

***Where am I wrong with my reasoning?***

Comment: You seem to be confusing "conservation of energy" (which is always true) and the definition of a "conservative force". Think about two simpler cases: (A) the block does not move at all and (B) you move it in a circle ending at its initial position. If friction was conservative, in case B the final temperature would be  *the same as in case A* - i.e. the friction would *not* generate any heat in the block.

Comment: Well, you are suddenly making the object of interest be (the block + the table), so now when you say "friction" acts on the object, it's no longer the same concept (it's not a force as defined by Newton, but something else - something that acts on two objects simultaneously - producing vibration, but only causing one of the objects to move). So that alone makes your argument muddy. You also use the term "vibration", but it's not precisely defined what it is and how to quantify it, so it's not clear if it's correct to say that the final state of the system is the same in both cases.

Comment: @alephzero Sorry if I sound dumb I may be wrong but ... When the block doesn't move then its initial and final states are the same ..  and now If we take a different path so that the initial and final positions are still the same then we will alter the initial and final states i.e we can't compare the work done by friction when the block is at rest and when the block follows a circular path to its initial position...

Comment: 1. The "warning" at the beginning communicates no useful information - that the question is long is self-evident, and one should *always* pay attention to the proper usage of terminology. 2. The entire idea here seems to rest on *"the state of the body in this case at final position is not the same, since the molecules of both the block and the table will now be vibrating at a faster rate"*, but this is simply not what "the state of the body" in classical mechanics and in the context of conservative forces means.

Comment: I worry that you have put way too much stock in my usage of the word "state" in the comments of my answer to your previous question.

Comment: @ACuriousMind then in what context is it used ?

Comment: "then in what context is it used ?" - in the context of the original definitions. Here, you're generalizing the idea of the state (you're changing what is meant by it); in itself, that is perhaps fine as a step towards some other formalism, but when you change the meaning of something, it may not make sense anymore within the original formalism. You're just assuming that this change has no effect on the old notions of friction and  force, and that they can retain their original meanings. But in your setup, is friction still an external force? Should you also generalize the notion of force?

Answer (score 6):

If you are just modeling the friction force as something simple such as

1. Proportional to the normal force $\mu N$, or
2. proportional to the velocity $-bv$

then these are obviously non-conservative, since the work by these will depend on the path taken between initial in final states and, in the case of the second one, how that path is traversed.

However, what you are doing is going deeper. Friction is essentially made up of electrostatic interactions (I'm sure one could get more complicated, but we will stick with this for this answer), and the electrostatic force *is* conservative. So, if you were to track all of the charge interactions (the electrostatic forces between all charges), you would be looking at work done by conservative forces.

Comment: why are  you mentioning **initial and final points** to compare work done. We need to have same initial and same final states to compare work ..  (this was essentially your answer to the spring question right ???)

Comment: @Ankit Sorry I'll change that word

Comment: Also if we have a given initial and a given final state then taking a different path may deviate us from the desired final state and thus we can't compare work done by friction along different paths to define it's conservativeness..... Btw can you please help me with the third case I have considered .. is there something wrong about it ?

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1**

> *I think we can also use the temperature of the system after
> (being displaced to point B) to define our final state.*

No you can't use the temperature alone.

The temperature is a measure of the *average* kinetic energy of the vibrating molecules, not the total kinetic energy associated with the vibrating molecules. If you push the block at constant velocity the temperature at the block/surface interface would theoretically be the same all along the distance covered, regardless of the amount of distance covered, whereas the amount of friction work done will be theoretically be proportional to the distance covered.

**Case 2**

> *Now if the same block is displaced slowly from the same
> initial state to the same final position but on a different path
> (let's say on two diagonal lines meeting at point C in that same
> horizontal plane), the friction will act for a longer distance and for
> a longer time and thus will do more work.*

Yes, and that proves the fact that kinetic friction work depends on the path between the A and B, i.e., that the kinetic friction force is not a conservative force.

> *But the main thing to notice here is that the state of the body in
> this case at final position is not the same ("since the molecules of
> both the block and the table will now be vibrating at a faster rate
> since friction acted over a longer distance (as well as longer time)
> or to say that the temperature of the system would be higher than that
> in the first case") which means that we cannot compare the work done
> by friction in these two cases to define whether it is conservative or
> not.*

The molecules will not be vibrating faster (higher temperature) for the longer path between A and B than the direct path between A and B, *but more molecules will be vibrating for the longer path*, for a greater total dissipated KE for the longer path, which will equal the friction work between A and B. Again proving that kinetic friction is not conservative.

**Case 3**

> *This time the friction acted for the same time and the same distance and thus the vibration or the temperature of the system will be the
> same and so we can now compare the work done by friction in this case
> and in case 1 and by coincidence we get the fact that the work done by
> friction is same in both these paths which means that friction is also
> a conservative force.*

Again, forget about the temperature since it is a measure of average kinetic energy along the distance, not the total kinetic energy dissipated as friction.

The sequence: (1) lift block from rest at C to rest at some height above C, (2) move block from rest above C to rest above B, and (3) lower block from rest above B to rest at B, involves no net work. The raising and lowering of the block involves gravity (a conservative force) and no net work (no change in gravitational potential energy) since the initial and final height are the same. Moving the block from rest above C to rest above B involves no change in kinetic energy, so from the work energy theorem, the net work there is zero.

The end result is no net work is done moving the block from C to B. The only work is moving the block from A to C which is the same as the work from A directly to B since the distance traveled is the same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "Yes, and that proves the fact that kinetic friction work depends on the path between the A and B, i.e., that the kinetic friction force is not a conservative force" but before saying that the work done by friction is different for different path taken and thus it is non conservative we should chack whether our initial and final states are same or not and this is definitely not conserved when a different path is taken which means that we cannot directly say that it is non conservative. **We need to have same initial and final states before comparing work along different paths**

Comment: @Ankit The initial and final states, in this case, is simply the initial and final position of the block being moved. You seem to be defining the initial and final  "states" in terms of the temperature at  the surfaces, are you not?  If not, then exactly how are you defining the initial and final states.

Comment: the state of the system should not only be decided on the basis of initial and final positions (this is what I read in my linked question).. it should account for both the table and the block ( I guess)...

Comment: see this comment by Cort Ammon in the question I have linked above ::--- **@Ankit As for the work done by a conservative force, it is independent of "path," but there's a nuance there which we sometimes miss at first. We have to talk about the entire system here. Thus the state of the system includes not just the position of the block, but how long the spring is (which might be different depending on how many times you wrap it around nails and such). – Cort Ammon**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to examine if a force is path-independent, then this obviously implies that the force is acting along the whole path. You can not just lift the block off the table for part of the path. If friction would be a conservative force you could go from A to B and back to A again without spending any energy.

Comment: Your last statement is wrong.. again I am insisting you to note that the states should be same before comparing work for same initial and final positions.  When we go from A to B and then come back from B to A our final state is not the same as our initial state . And that's why we can't compare these two situations to decide conservativeness

Comment: *"Your last statement is wrong"* No, it isn't at all. *If friction would be a conservative force you could go from A to B and back to A again without spending any energy* is exactly right and the textbook definition of a conservative force.

Comment: You're very fixated on this temperature thing. But the energy that is 'lost'$^\dagger$ to friction manifests itself in several ways: heat is one, sound often another, vibrations can play a part too. $^\dagger$ I use quotemarks because energy is of course never really lost, only transformed.

Comment: @Gert thanks for your reply... But even I was not sure on that temperature thing ..

Comment: @Gert one more thing if the block follows a circular path to its initial position then its initial and final state would not be the same because of the reasons you wrote (heat , sound and vibrations )... So if the states are not the same then how can we define conservativeness ??

Comment: *"So if the states are not the same then how can we define conservativeness ??"* You would 'conservativeness' if NO energy was 'lost' to friction.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of "conservative force" only depends on how that force varies with the position of the object being acted upon by that force. No other property matters except position. The fact that the block and table change temperature is irrelevant as to whether the frictional force is conservative. Only position matters.

[Regarding your question about the spring](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/652804/): the usual equation for the force of a spring is $F=-kx$, where $x$ is the displacement of the mass from the natural length of the spring. When the nail is introduced, that equation is no longer an accurate description of the force felt by the block. The spring force alone is a conservative force. The spring force with a nail is not a conservative force because of the path dependence introduced by the nail.

Comment: I suggest deleting your second paragraph and posting it as an answer to the previous question instead. This post should only be an answer to this question.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Since this question and the linked question represent the same confusion, I'm trying to get ahead of some of the questions that the OP might have. If this were a more general question regarding a more common confusion, I would follow your advice so other readers could get more out of it. However, since I think the confusion here is specific to the OP, I'm writing more for their sake.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of categorising "conservative forces" is to be a ble to define a potential energy function for the force. Potential energy is a function of an object's position and NOT of its generalised state.

So, in the definition of a conservative force, take "state" to mean "position". This is the only reason we talk about conservative forces. These are the forces which can be expressed as the gradient of a scalar function of the **position vector**. The scalar function is called the potential energy. Having a potential energy function makes calculations easier.

Since there doesn't exist a potential energy function for friction, it's not a conservative force.